# RxJS: using repeat after takeUntil creates a subscription leak

Tags: memory-leaks, rxjs

I have the following scenario: I want to subscribe to `source1` and when it doesn't emit anything for at least 2000ms, I want to emit from `fallback`. However, when `source1` emits again, I want to switch back to `source1` and so on.

I have an implementation that works, however it creates a subscription leak because `repeat` is used after `takeUntil`. This is explained in details in this [nice article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef). I can't figure out how to get rid of this leak while keeping the same behaviour. Is there a way?

```
const source1: Observable;
const fallback: Observable;

const b = source2.pipe(takeUntil(source1));
const a = source1.pipe(timeoutWith(2000, b), repeat());

a.subscribe(console.log)
```

You can play with this simple repro case https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-repeat-learnrxjs-ah9j5r?file=index.ts

Comment: `repeat` operator will keep the subscription running until `unsubscribe`. In your example, a memory leak will happen when the subscription will keep running even after unsubscribing. I did try to unsubscribe and the subscription was torn down [example - I unsubscribed after 20 seconds]. What your meaning of memory leak?

Comment: @user2216584 in my example, a new subscription is created every time the behaviour is repeated. You can read more about it in the article that I've linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer didn't work, you're quite right. I think this does the trick though:

```js
source1.pipe(
  switchMap(val => merge(of(val), source2.pipe(delay(2000))))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: No it's not, I want an Observable that emits form `source1` and if `source1` stops emitting for at least 2 seconds, it switches to `fallback` until `source1` emits again. And so on

Comment: Not really, the final `Observable`, the one you subscribe to should emit those values.  If I remove the `tap` from your example and do `.subscribe(console.log)`, you can see that the emitted values are not correct.

Comment: Awesome, this version is what I want

Comment: Just found an edge case though, this starts to work only after `source1` has emitted at least one value. So, if I subscribe to this observable and after 2 seconds, `source1` has not emitted, then of course, the final Observable does not emit any value. I don't see an easy way to fix it...

Comment: You could add a `startWith` with a bogus value you can test for. That way you're certain to get an emission. Either that or you have `source1` be a `BehaviorSubject`.